# Adding content (including iframes) via innerHTML is incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Create simple page that loading into div some content by innerHTML, but when i use this javascript:

```
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = 
   '<iframe id="test1" class="yt-embed " style="top: 50px; width: 98%; height: 80%; margin-left: 1%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7Ui_FnOPh8?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen="false" frameborder="0" /><br>TEST';
```

But everything after iframe is not added. 
Does anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `iframe` cannot be self-terminated as in: `<iframe />`. You must provide an explicit closing tag for the element:

```html
 
       <iframe id="test1" class="yt-embed " style="top: 50px; width: 98%; height: 80%; margin-left: 1%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R7Ui_FnOPh8?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen="false" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>TEST
```

Comment: I know. That's why I posted it as the answer.

Comment: So it was so easy. Thanks a lot :)